# Hibernate get parent's id from child entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

a lot of people have posted very similar problems, but I can't seem to find one that addresses my circumstance.

I have a parent entity `Dnar` and a child entity `WorkLocationSuburb`. A `Dnar` has one-to-many `WorkLocationSuburbs`.

Normally, I would define this relationship as follows:

**The child**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "req_work_suburb", schema = SCHEMA)
public class WorkLocationSuburb {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "req_work_suburb_seq")
  @GenericGenerator(strategy="sequence", name="req_work_suburb_seq", parameters={@Parameter(name="sequence", value=SCHEMA+".req_work_suburb_seq")})
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="suburb", length=255, nullable=false)
  private String suburb;

  //remainder omitted
}
```

**The parent**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "req_dnar", schema = SCHEMA)
@Inheritance(strategy = JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "form_type", discriminatorType = STRING, length = 64)
public abstract class Dnar {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "req_dnar_seq")
  @GenericGenerator(strategy = "sequence", name = "req_dnar_seq", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = SCHEMA + ".req_dnar_seq") })
  @Column(name = C_DNAR_ID, nullable = false)
  private Long dnarId;

  @Column(name = "original_id")
  private Long originalId;


  @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, fetch = EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "dnar_id", nullable=false)
  private Set<WorkLocationSuburb> workLocationSuburbs;

  //remainder omitted
}
```

The above example works, and when I manually query the `req_work_suburb` table, I can see that it has a `dnar_id` column and that the column is being correctly populated. All good, so far!

In some query code, I create a criteria query that is dependent on the value of `req_work_suburb.dnar_id`:

```
  private static Specification<SubmittedDnarSummary> suburbIs(final String suburb) {
    return new Specification<SubmittedDnarSummary>(){
      @Override
      public Predicate toPredicate(Root<SubmittedDnarSummary> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        Subquery<Long> subquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
        Root<WorkLocationSuburb> suburbRoot = subquery.from(WorkLocationSuburb.class);
        return cb.in(root.get("dnarId")).value(subquery.select(suburbRoot.<Long>get("dnarId")).where(cb.equal(suburbRoot.get("suburb"), suburb)));
      }
    };
  }
```

When I execute the above, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unable to resolve attribute [dnarId] against path; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [dnarId] against path
         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:301)
         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:106)
         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
         at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:58)
         at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
         at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:163)
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:91)
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
         at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
         at $Proxy253.findAll(Unknown Source)
         at au.com.wpcorp.sys.dnar.spring.manager.impl.SearchManagerImpl.search(SearchManagerImpl.java:66)
         at au.com.wpcorp.sys.dnar.spring.mvc.controller.search.DnarSearchController.results(DnarSearchController.java:97)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
         at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
         at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
         at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
         at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
         at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
         at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
         at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
         at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
         at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
         at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
         at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
         at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
         at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
         at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
         at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve attribute [dnarId] against path
         at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.unknownAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:118)
         at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.locateAttribute(AbstractPathImpl.java:223)
         at org.hibernate.ejb.criteria.path.AbstractPathImpl.get(AbstractPathImpl.java:194)
         at au.com.wpcorp.sys.dnar.spring.manager.impl.SearchManagerImpl$3.toPredicate(SearchManagerImpl.java:141)
         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.applySpecificationToCriteria(SimpleJpaRepository.java:480)
         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:436)
         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.getQuery(SimpleJpaRepository.java:421)
         at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:303)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
         at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:334)
         at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:319)
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
         at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
         at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
         ... 49 more
```

It appears to be failing because Hibernate can't find a property called `dnarId` on `WorkLocationSuburb`. My question is, how can I add this information to `WorkLocationSuburb` without Hibernate complaining about some other problem? It seems I need some code like:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "req_work_suburb", schema = SCHEMA)
public class WorkLocationSuburb {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "req_work_suburb_seq")
  @GenericGenerator(strategy="sequence", name="req_work_suburb_seq", parameters={@Parameter(name="sequence", value=SCHEMA+".req_work_suburb_seq")})
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="suburb", length=255, nullable=false)
  private String suburb;

  @Column(name="dnar_id", nullable=false)  // column definition added here
  private Long dnarId;

  //remainder omitted
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the above additional column to work? This column **must be** automatically populated with the parent's `dnarId`.

Thanks,
Muel.

---

**Updated with JB Nizet's suggestions**

My code is now like so:

**The child**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "req_work_suburb", schema = SCHEMA)
public class WorkLocationSuburb {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "req_work_suburb_seq")
  @GenericGenerator(strategy="sequence", name="req_work_suburb_seq", parameters={@Parameter(name="sequence", value=SCHEMA+".req_work_suburb_seq")})
  @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="suburb", length=255, nullable=false)
  private String suburb;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="dnar_id", nullable=false)
  private Dnar dnar;

  //remainder omitted
}
```

**The parent**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "req_dnar", schema = SCHEMA)
@Inheritance(strategy = JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "form_type", discriminatorType = STRING, length = 64)
public abstract class Dnar {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "req_dnar_seq")
  @GenericGenerator(strategy = "sequence", name = "req_dnar_seq", parameters = { @Parameter(name = "sequence", value = SCHEMA + ".req_dnar_seq") })
  @Column(name = C_DNAR_ID, nullable = false)
  private Long dnarId;

  @Column(name = "original_id")
  private Long originalId;

  @OneToMany(cascade = ALL, fetch = EAGER, orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="dnar")
  private Set<WorkLocationSuburb> workLocationSuburbs = new LinkedHashSet<WorkLocationSuburb>();


  @PostPersist
  void setChildRefs() {
    for (WorkLocationSuburb suburb : workLocationSuburbs) {
      suburb.setDnar(this);
    }
  }

  //remainder omitted
}
```

When I attempt to save a `Dnar` that has a `WorkLocationSuburb` attached, I see the following order of events:

1. The `Dnar` is inserted into the database
2. `@PostConstuct` is invoked and the `WorkLocationSuburb` gets a reference to the parent `Dnar`. The parent `Dnar` has been assigned an ID correctly.
3. The insertion of child `WorkLocationSuburb` is attempted, but results in the following exception: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("DNAR"."REQ_WORK_SUBURB"."DNAR_ID")`

What am I still doing incorrectly? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make the association bidirectional:

```
public class WorkLocationSuburb {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Dnar parentDnar;
    // ...
}

public class Dnar {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentDnar", ...)
    private Set<WorkLocationSuburb> suburbs;
    // ...
}
```

Just be aware that in a bidirectional OneToMany association, the owning side of the association is always the many side (the side which doesn't have the `mappedBy` attribute). This means the Hibernate will only consider the `WorkLocationSuburb.parentDnar` field to decide if the association exists. This thus means that each time you add a suburb to a dnar, you must also set the suburb's dnar field:

```
public void addSuburb(WorkLocationSuburb suburb) {
    this.suburbs.add(suburb);
    suburb.setParentDnar(this);
}
```

Similarly, if you remove a suburb from a dnar, you should set the parentDnar of the suburb to null.

Regarding the query, you can now use the `parentDnar` field in your query. Remember that JPA queries always work on entities and their persistent fields/properties. Never on table and their columns.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but Hibernate doesn't understand how to populate the foreign key column on the child entity. What did I miss, please? Oh and I appended the code I tried to the above question.

Comment: Try not using a PostPersist hook to set the parent IDs. I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to modify entities in such callback methods. Just do it by encapsulating it in your entity or service methods.